# Stack only a single row in a responsive html table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-tables

I want to stack only single row in a responsive html table using css.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="firstrow">
            <td colspan="2">Description 1</td>
            <td colspan="2">Content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description 3</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px grey solid;
}
table td {
    border: 1px lime solid;
}
table .firstrow td {
    display: block;
}
```

But the stacked row has only the width of one of the following table rows.

[image]

If I apply the `display: block` to all `td`s in all table rows it spreads the whole width as expected.

[image]

How can I get the full width stacking for a single table row?

Comment: Have you thought about not using tables and instead using something like Divs?

Comment: @imvain2 I considered to do so but for semantic reasons I'ld like to stick to tables.

Comment: Why are you appying `rowspan=2` if the remaining rows both have only 2 columns? Please try and share an interactive code example in your question.